# How to highlight selected text

Tags: google-docs, formatting

Did Google for some reason remove the feature to highlight selected text in a document?

How can it be done now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still there, though I believe they changed the menu items.

- Select your text
- Click the `Text Color` button in the toolbar (it looks like an **A** with a line underneath it)
- Click the `Highlight` Pane in the top right
- Select your highlight color

[image]